# Syntax to SubSelect in a Linq Select

Tags: c#, linq

I have a syntax problem and need some smart folks than me.

Here is my select statement

```
    var Materials = from j in db.Jobs
                join je in db.a_Job_Extensions on j.Top_Lvl_Job equals je.Job
                join mr in db.Material_Reqs on j.Job1 equals mr.Job
                join m in db.Materials on mr.Material equals m.Material1
                where jobList.Contains(j.Top_Lvl_Job)
                select new 
                { 
                    je.PCR,
                    mr.Job,
                    j.Top_Lvl_Job,
                    OrderQty = ((from j1 in db.Jobs where j1.Job1 == j.Top_Lvl_Job select new { j1.Order_Quantity}).FirstOrDefault()).ToString(),
                    j.Part_Number,
                    mr.Material,
                    mr.Description,
                    mr.Est_Qty,
                    m.Status,
                    theClass = m.Class == null? "": m.Class
                };
```

The j1.Order_Quantity is a double in the Job table. But when I run the query, it returns a value of "{ Order_Quantity = 607 }".

My desire is to have it return just the value of "607".

What am I doing wrong here?

The code was originally trying to bring it out as a double, but I switch to string to see what was coming out. I'm coming from a sql background so I must be missing something silly.

Comment: Change `new { j1.Order_Quantity}` to `j1.Order_Quantity`.

Comment: Instead of `select new { ... }` have `select j1.Order_Quantity`.

Comment: can't you use `let` here instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
((from j1 in db.Jobs where j1.Job1 == j.Top_Lvl_Job select 
    j1.Order_Quantity.ToString()).FirstOrDefault())
```